# Menu dropdown já existente (sem bootstrap) parou de funcionar após uso da biblioteca bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-3, menu, dropdown

Possuo na página do cliente um menu dropdown que o cliente não quer troca. Precisei inserir um modal na página e utilizei bootstrap, funcionou numa boa. O problema é que o menu dropdown do cliente não funciona mais. Já tentei de tudo e não consegui fazer ele funcionar:

- já troquei a classe de nome;
- troquei para `id`, mas nada resolveu;
- até no `z-index` tentei.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Lembrando que sem importar o css do bootstrap, o menu funciona perfeito.

Segue o code do menu:

```
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

css do boostrap:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: pode incluir o seu HTML na pergunta? vai facilitar alguém conseguir ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convenci o cliente a trocar o dropdown!